# Cómo puedo mostrar un icono dentro de un canvas?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy dibujando en un canvas un icono personalizado para mi app y me preguntaba cómo puedo hacer para mostrar uno de los iconos de material o fontawesome dentro de mi custom painter. Intento hacerlo de varias formas pero siempre se muestra el icono con un signo de interrogación sin importar el icono que le ponga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
class CustomMarker extends CustomPainter {
  final String label;
  final Color color;

  CustomMarker(this.label, this.color);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();

    // Draw rectangle
    paint.color = Colors.white;
    final rect1 = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    final RRect rRect1 =
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect1, const Radius.circular(10));
    canvas.drawRRect(rRect1, paint);

    paint.color = color;
    final rect = Rect.fromLTWH(2.5, 2.5, size.width - 5, size.height - 5);
    final RRect rRect =
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, const Radius.circular(10));
    canvas.drawRRect(rRect, paint);

    paint.color = Colors.white;

    // Draw cicle pointer
    paint.color = Colors.white;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.width / 2, size.height), 15, paint);

    paint.color = Colors.blue;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.width / 2, size.height), 10, paint);

    // Draw text label
    final fishCodePoint = FontAwesomeIcons.fish.codePoint;

    final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(
            text: String.fromCharCode(Icons.login.codePoint),
            style: const TextStyle(
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              fontSize: 30,
              color: Colors.white,
            )),
        maxLines: 1,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);

    textPainter.layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: size.width - 40);
    textPainter.paint(
        canvas, Offset(40, size.height / 2 - textPainter.size.height / 2));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomMarker oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pude lograrlo incluyendo en el string el unicode del símbolo o icono que quería mostrar.

Hice esta modificación en el TextPainter:

```
final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(
            text: '\u{2199}',
            style: const TextStyle(
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                fontSize: 30,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        maxLines: 1,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
```

Y se muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busque el unicode de los símbolos aqui: https://unicode-table.com/en/